# Finding the magnitude of F

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

An object with the weight of $80N$ is balanced with the force of $F$  as seen on the diagram. What is the magnitude of $F$? (Ignore the weight of pulley and friction)

$\sum F_y = 0$

$F_y \sin 37 - 80 = 0 \implies F_y \sin 37 = 80 \implies F_y = 133.33N$

$\sum F_x = 0$

$F_x \cos 37 = 0 \implies F_x = 0$

Finally, we have

$F = 133.33N$

Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Your calculations are incorrect.

There are two sides of the cable around the pulley that helps to support the 80 N load. See the diagrams below. So the vertical force from the cable around the pulley is $F+F\sin(37)$, not $F_y\sin(37)$. This gives the sum of vertical forces as $F+F\sin(37)-80=0$ from which F=49.9 N. (Note that $F_y\sin(37)$ does not make sense.)

The horizontal force from the cable around the pulley is $F\cos(37)$, not $F_x\cos(37)$. Furthermore, there is a force in the horizontal "rope" of magnitude T, so the sum of forces in the horizontal forces is $F\cos(37)-T=0$ from which T=39.9N.

Here is a free body diagram showing all of the forces acting on the pulley. The statement to neglect the friction in the pulley indicates that the tension in the cable is the same value, F, on each side of the pulley.

[image: free body diagram] or like this [image: FBD 2]

Comment: Does the question seem incorrect? because everyone finds anohter answer.

Comment: If two people get a different answer to the same question, I think the problem is not with the question. ;-) If my free body diagram is reasonable, then your answer of F=133 N indicates that it takes somewhere between 133 N (if just one F holding the pulley) to maybe as much as 266 N (two F's because you are saying the angle is really 90 degrees since Fx=0) to hold up an 80 N weight. Does that seem correct?

Comment: Yes, However. 19 people found the answer 57.12N or 133.33N. So, am so scared.

Comment: I agree with this answer. If  Fx=0 angle woold be 90 degree, not 37 degree.

Comment: @Katarina Which answer seems right? or is there anything going wrong with the question?

Comment: am really out of my mind right now. Everyone finds anohter answer which doesn't make any sense! Is there something going wrong with the question?

Comment: Maybe someone who is getting a different answer (like 57.12) can post their free body diagram and how they get that answer. Then someone will be able to see if there is a mistake. In the meantime, you could do a simple experiment if you have 3 spring scales and a protractor. Setup a weight and geometry as stated in the problem and measure the tensions at each of the 3 ends of the ropes. (You may need to scale the weight from 80 N to some other value depending on the limit of your spring scales.)

Comment: @JohnHoltz However, are they wrong or something? You won't believe but $24$ people found different answers. Some of them had just found the answer as $50N$. Or am I missing something while asking the question? Maybe they think anohter thing concerning the question.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Are you there?

Comment: I think 50 N (the "answer found by some" that you now report) equals 49.9 N (my answer) if you round off the values. It also depends on whether you calculate the sine(37) or use the approximation of sine(37)=0.6 which I found suggested in the problem statement when I searched the internet for your question. (https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/object-whose-weight-balanced-force-seen-diagram-note-pulley-frictionless-find-magnitude-fo-q29587573)

Comment: @JohnHoltz What should we think from that solution? Are they incorrect? It seems like there should be anything going wrong with the question or people. I'm getting the answer $50N$ rarely when I compare to other answers. Thereby, I want to know a strong reason because we're speaking for $24$ people, who found the answer different.

Comment: @JohnHoltz I'd be too grateful if you reply my last question if necessary :)

Comment: Engineering is not a popularity contest. It does not matter how many people get an answer, that does not make it correct. The questions from me to you are: (1) do you see why 133 N is the wrong answer? If not, you need to ask about what you do not understand. (2) Do you have the calculations by someone else that gets an answer other than 50 N? If so, how did they calculate it? Or what did they do differently from my calculation? We do not have their details, so we cannot tell you what they are doing differently.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Then do you see anymistake/unclear things in my question?

Comment: The question is clear.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Do you like chegg? I'd like to get your thinkings. All the answers I received was from chegg.

Comment: They are still equating $F\sin 37 = 80$